# jQuery limit what accepts a click() event

Tags: jquery, click

Sorry for the bad name, but I have a few approaches in my head and I don't know which if any have potential here. I am trying to make it so that I click on a table cell a Javascript function is called, but only if the child element within that table cell, the 'a' was not clicked on.

Here's some html I have. I can't modify it.

```
<td class="DayStyle" align="right" style="color:#CEE2ED;border-color:#CEE2ED;border-width:3px;   border-style:solid;width:14%;">
    <a title="July 19" style="color:#CEE2ED" href="javascript:__doPostBack('myCal','4217')">19</a>
</td>
```

I'm using this jQuery to accomplish this right now:

```
$(".myCal").find("td.DayStyle").click(function() {
   //DoStuff
});
```

If, within this function, I get '$(this).attr("class"))', I always get DayStyle, assumingly that's because that's what caught the click.

The behavior that results is that DoStuff happens when the user clicks on either the table cell or the text/"a" within the table. The behavior I want is that DoStuff only happens when the table cell is clicked, but not the text within it.

Approaches I'm considering::
1) Trying to also capture .click() events that click the "a" element and do nothing.
2) Finding where the user is clicking and check if there is text or an "a" at that location.
3) Somehow specifying in the click function that clicking on the "a" or anything with a "title" attribute or something isn't okay.

Comment: avoid using javascript: link in href. Non-javascript users will be redirected to that link

Comment: @genesis he pointed out that he can't change that html.  Looks to be a .Net control.

Comment: You guessed it. ASP.NET calendar control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

```
$(".myCal").find("td.DayStyle").click(function(e) {
   if($(e.target).hasClass('DayStyle')) {

   }
});
```

or

```
if(!$(e.target).is('a')) {

}
```

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks. I'll check out the event API first next time -- jQuery sure is powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('td.DayStyle a').click(function(event){

    try
    {
        // Prevent click event from travelling up the DOM tree
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        // IE does it this way
        window.event.cancelBubble=true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you need an `event` parameter in your event handling function.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use delegate in this case to optimize your code.

```
$(".myCal").delegate("td.DayStyle", "click", function(e) {
   if(!$(e.target).is('a')) {
      //do Stuff
   }else{ //do nothing or someother logic goes here }
});
```

Comment: Doubt it would improve performance here. It's a good alternative to `live()`, though.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind this, Shankar? Why is it better?

Comment: This will attach click event to only .myCal container and not to all td's in the table. Just by looking at the target you can decide which element has triggered the event.